# HTML align all column values to the center with one table parameter

Tags: html, center

I am trying to generate a table in HTML, and want to align all table values to the center, **without specifying alignment for each cell** (I want to have one piece of code, at the beginning of the table)

Is there a table parameter I can set, at the beginning of the code, to help me do that?

Sample code with two rows:

```
<table border="1"><TR><TD>1</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>4</TD></TR><TR><TD>1aaaaaa</TD><TD>2aaaaa</TD><TD>3aaaaa</TD><TD>4aaaa</TD></TR></table>
```

Comment: The vertical center or the horizontal center, or both? And can you use CSS?

Comment: `<table style="text-align: center" border="1">` would do the horizontal center if there's no other CSS that would override it.

Comment: use css, instead of hard code

Comment: Thank you David, this is exactly what I was looking for - Do you want to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make David's (above) answer more visible:

To get data in all cells within a table to line up, use the following:

```
<table style="text-align: center;" border="1">
```

Working example:

```html
<table border="1" style="text-align: center;"><TR><TD>1</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>4</TD></TR><TR><TD>1aaaaaa</TD><TD>2aaaaa</TD><TD>3aaaaa</TD><TD>4aaaa</TD></TR></table>
```

In my case, this helped reduce a lot of redundant code. Hopefully this will help others do the same.